# Cin error when using arrays

Tags: visual-c++

I was writing a program that should sort by grade and I wanted to also have the names along with it (It's not done, I ran into the error and tried to fix just the error code). But when I try to run my program it takes in one value then skips the rest of the code

Here is what I wrote:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numb[7], name[7], Lname[7];
    int i, j;
    char swap;

    // Taking in and associating names, last names, and grades

    for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
    cout << "Please input the student's name: " << endl;
    cin  >> name[i];
    cout << "Please enter their last name" << endl;
    cin >> Lname[i];
    cout << "Please enter their grade" << endl;
    cin >> numb[i];
 }
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
        cout << name[i] << ' ' << Lname[i] << " Got a " << numb << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the arrays as integers which means what you cin should be integer values (0 to 7), not strings (such as an actual name). Not sure if that's what you want to do in this code or not.

In the second for loop it should also be numb[i].